# Edit a picklist field and conditionally render vf page on opportunity page layout

Tags: visualforce

I have a picklist field on my opportunity in which I am selecting FX BankNow value.  When that is selected, i want the VF page to open/render so that the additional fields are populated.

[image: Opportunity layout]

[image: VF Page]

VF Code:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock title="Enter Product Details">
              <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true"/>                                
              </apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlock > 
<apex:pageBlockSection >                      
<apex:actionRegion >                  
<apex:outputPanel id="MainPanel">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Product Details" rendered="{!Opportunity.Specialized_Product__c == 'FX BankNow'}">  
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:outputpanel>
</apex:actionRegion>                   
</apex:pageBlockSection>                 
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="true">  
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Service_Code__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Owner_Officer_Code__c}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Cash__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Credit__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Spread_Matrix__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Currency_Usage__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Max_Amount_USD_Equivalent__c}"/>

</apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] so that we know exactly what you are asking. See [ask] for more. Thanks!

Comment: I need assistance with when i select FX BankNow on the Specialized Product of the opportunity, the vf page is not rendering.  so whats currently going on is when i set that field and save the opportunity record, i cant get the vf page to open.

Comment: Your Visualforce page does not contain an edit component for this field. Are you trying to conditionally embed this page within the standard Opportunity page layout? Again, could you please [edit] your question to provide complete and detailed context?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to happen.  I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Salesforce Classic, you cannot conditionally render page layout components as such - not in the way that you can conditionally render Lightning components on a record page.

You also cannot react to edit events on the standard page layout "live", as the user works. Your page would only be rendered after the user saves.

You can implement the entire page layout as a Visualforce page overriding the Edit and/or View actions, and in that context you have full control over the layout and rendering. However, this means you have to build and maintain all of the standard functionality that Salesforce provides out of the box.

You can embed a Visualforce page in the standard page layout and make a choice about what to render there based upon the record values, but the real estate reserved for that embed on the page layout is always going to be present regardless of what you choose to render in that space. You could also choose to conditionally render a link to open another page, which would reduce the space you need to allocate.

It's not really clear what the context and specific requirement you have around this Visualforce page may be, but those at a high level are some of the options available to you.